# Segue after new user creation using firebase not being performed -Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am having issues with two segues however, since I used the same logic in the implementation of each of these segues I'm going to go ahead and condense everything into one question. Basically, I am trying to initialize a segue after performing `createUser` function with firebase and after performing `login` function also handled by Firebase, however, when the `SignUp` and `Login` buttons are clicked there seems to be no response to the segue being called. Below is the code for each of the `@IBActions`

```
 @IBAction func signUpComplete(_ sender: Any) {
    FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: signUpEmailField.text!, password: signUpPasswordField.text!, completion: { (user: FIRUser?, error) in
        if self.signUpEmailField.text == "" || self.signUpPasswordField.text == "" {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Oops!", message: "A valid E-mail and Password are Required", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
                    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)



        if FIRAuthErrorCode.errorCodeEmailAlreadyInUse != nil {

            let emailExists = UIAlertController(title: "Oops!", message: "A user with this E-Mail already exists!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            emailExists.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
            self.present(emailExists, animated: true, completion: nil)


            }

        else {

            DispatchQueue.main.async () {
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "signUpSucceededSegue", sender: self)
            }
            }

            }
        })
}
```

and

```
@IBAction func loginButton(_ sender: Any) {

    FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: emailLoginField.text!, password: passwordLoginField.text!, completion: { (user: FIRUser?, error) in
            if self.emailLoginField.text == "" || self.passwordLoginField.text == ""{

                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "E-Mail is Required", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

            if FIRAuthErrorCode.errorCodeUserNotFound != nil {

                let invalidLogin = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "E-Mail/Password Incorrect", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                invalidLogin.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
                self.present(invalidLogin, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }

        else{


                DispatchQueue.main.async () {

                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginSucceededSegue", sender: self)

                }

            }


        }
    })
```

are there any glaring logical errors at first glance or is there a better way to implement a segue into these functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Embed a Navigation Controller to the very first view of your storyboard
- Then Try using this code:-

  ```
  @IBAction func signUpComplete(_ sender: Any) {


  if self.signUpEmailField.text == "" || self.signUpPasswordField.text == "" {

      let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Oops!", message: "A valid E-mail and Password are Required", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
      alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
      self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

  }else{

      FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: self.signUpEmailField!.text, password: self.signUpPasswordField!.text, completion: { (user, err) in

          if let ErrorCode = FIRAuthErrorCode(rawValue: err!._code){

              switch ErrorCode {

              case .errorCodeEmailAlreadyInUse : let emailExists = UIAlertController(title: "Oops!", message: "A user with this E-Mail already exists!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                                                 emailExists.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
                                                 self.present(emailExists, animated: true, completion: nil)

                                                 break

              default                      :  break 

              }

          }else{

              let nextView = self.navigationController!.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "signUpSucceededSegue")
              self.navigationController!.pushViewController(nextView, animated: true)

          }
      })
    }
  }
  ```

Then alter your other code-block in the similar fashion.